# How to check that the internet is actually available in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in Android and I am working to develop an application that requires internet connection. but I can't find any API function to detecting changes on internet connection as shown in the following pictures

[Device connected to a network and Internet is not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1XtA.png)

[Device connected to a network and Internet is available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqzMv.png)

I have tried the following code but it is not what I want

```
public static boolean checkInternetConenction(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager
            cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetwork != null
            && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

The previous code only returns if the device is connected to a network or not.

Comment: I expected this answer, but is there a way to catch this event from the system without trying connecting to a server? I mean by the system

Comment: No, System doesn't provide anything to detect that. Thanks